# VS CODE error S5057 cannot find a tsconfig.json file at the specified directory: '.'

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am having fits getting visual studio code going with my angular 2 starter project.

I have set up my **tsconfig.json** like so ...

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Immediately I came across this error

```
  [ts] Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
class AppComponent
```

I could not identify what was going on so I ran a build and got this error.

```
error TS5057: Cannot find a tsconfig.json file at the specified directory: '.'
```

This error explains why I am getting errors about the component decorator, but I am not sure why the **tsconfig.json** file is not being found.

I only have one folder and it is holding everything except index.html, package.json and .gitignore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the most people on Visual Studio Code, it will be sufficient just to create `tsconfig.json` file in the document root (that's probably where your `.ts` files are) with simple contents: `{}`.

This means "an empty JSON file <...>. This will be sufficient for most people."

Comment: the source link is broken

Comment: @opensas right, they removed this document. They used to have a separate FAQ for questions related to `tsconfig.json` problems. Not anymore. I'll remove the source link then.

Answer (score 12):

I got similar error. Solved by changing following line in tasks.json

`"args": ["-p", "."],`

to

`"args": ["-p", "./src"],`

In my case tsconfig.json was was in src folder. The Angular 2 project was created using angular-cli.

Answer (score 3):

I put the tsconfig.js into the root folder, then I can build my .ts file anywhere in the project folder.

Comment: I had to use ```ng serve``` instead of ```ng start``` and that solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Encountered a similar issue.

Tested on Debian 8.4 and Windows 7 SP1, with VS Code versions 1.1.0-insider, 1.0.0, 0.10.8. Also with and without setting `typescript.tsdk` in `.vscode/settings.json`.

In all cases, the contents of `tsconfig.json` seem to be disregarded in favour of the defaults. Running tsc from the terminal, the VS Code tslint plugin,  gulp-typescript, and more all make use the file without error, including the modules, decorators, and rules properties.

However, I'm not receiving the TS5057 during a VS Code task managed build unless I rename or remove the file despite the contents being disregarded.

As a temporary measure, you can set `typescript.validate.enable` to `false` in your settings and use the tslint plugin for validation while compiling via grunt or gulp, which can be integrated into the task runner if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I did the following:

```
ng new project_name
cd project_name
code .
```

Opening the src folder instead of the project root folder fixed it:

```
ng new project_name
cd project_name
code .\src
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Visual Studio Code and had the same problem. I solved it this way:
When you define a working folder for your project and add a task, VSC creates an invisible folder called .vscode. Inside that folder, there is where task.json lives and from that point, it is executed.

```
.vscode (folder)
    task.json
myfolder
    app.ts
    index.html
otherfolder
    newfile.ts
    otherfile.ts
tsconfig.json
```

the position of the tsconfig.json file is at the same level of the vscode folder. This is what "args": ["."], means at the task.json file.

Just put the tsconfig.json at the expected location